# native library is not getting loaded to apex_defaults from golang conditional implementation?

Tags: android, go, build, android-source

So I wrote a go file which will dynamically append one library to apex_defaults-> multilib -> first -> native_shared_libs; full code of `Android.bp` can be checked [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/heads/master/apex/Android.bp#21). However I can not see the compiled .so file in my out directory like other lib .so files generated.

**Long Explanation:**

I want to add a library named "libabcxtractor" to the array [native_shared_libs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/heads/master/apex/Android.bp#21); for that matter I wrote a `.go` file(as recommended by Google) with some condition which looks like this:

```
package my_apex

import (
    "android/soong/android"
    "android/soong/apex"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)



func globalFlags(ctx android.BaseContext) []string {
        var native_shared_libs []string
        if(strings.Contains(ctx.AConfig().DeviceName(), "my_apex_device")){
                fmt.Println("Some log to verify condition is getting executed......")
                native_shared_libs = append(native_shared_libs, "libabcextractor")
        }

        return native_shared_libs
}

func myApexFlagsDefaults(ctx android.LoadHookContext) {
    type props struct {
                Multilib struct {
                        First struct {
                                native_shared_libs  []string
                        }
                }
        }
        p := &props{}
        p.Multilib.First.native_shared_libs = globalFlags(ctx)
        ctx.AppendProperties(p)
}

func myApexFlagsDefaultsFactory() android.Module {
        module := apex.DefaultsFactory()
        android.AddLoadHook(module, myApexFlagsDefaults)
        return module
}

func init() {
        fmt.Println("Registering module type....")
        android.RegisterModuleType("my_apex_defaults", myApexFlagsDefaultsFactory)
}
```

To enable above go condition to get picked at build time, I have updated my `Android.bp` file as below:

```
bootstrap_go_package {
   name: "soong-my_apex",
   pkgPath: "frameworks/av/apex/build",
   deps: [ "soong-apex" ],
   srcs: [ "my_apex.go", ],
   pluginFor: ["soong_build"],
}

my_apex_defaults {
   name: "my_apex",
}

apex_defaults {
    name: "com.android.media-defaults",
    java_libs: ["updatable-media"],
    defaults: ["my_apex",] //THIS IS TO INCLUDE GO IMPLEMENTATION 
    multilib: {
```

When executing make command I can see it enters the conditional statement; the logs are getting printed. I further investigated by verifying whether my `.go` file gets compiled by checking the path `out/soong/.bootstrap/soong-my_apex/pkg/frameworks/av/apex/build.a`. It's there. However `".so"` file for `libabcextractor` is not being generated. Any help on this would be great.

**Edit:**
`libabcextractor` is a vendor library which resides in Prebuilts path. If I try with any other library which is part of AOSP code and is in the existing `native_static_libs` array already, it is not working for them as well. From here on I am unable to debug further because of unavailability of proper documentations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection in Go can only access exported struct fields, which are the ones that start with an uppercase letter. In your `First` struct, `native_shared_libs` is unexported and cannot be accessed using reflection.

Since the build process uses reflection to access the `props` struct, it cannot find information from it. You can change it like this:

```
type props struct {
    Multilib struct {
        First struct {
           Native_shared_libs  []string
        }
    }
}
```