# Applying conditions on "optional_subdirs" using Golang in Android.bp?

Tags: android, go, android-source

In our AOSP source code, There is one library in this path `vendar/myvendor/apps/Dialer/SomeLib` Since `SomeLib` is in 2nd level of apps directory. We needed to add below in `Dialer` app's `Android.bp` in order to include `SomeLib` at build time:

```
optional_subdirs = [
    ....
    "*",
]
```

So as expected `SomeLib` is getting picked up at build time. However This Lib should be picked for a particular target and not for others. To do that, I want to write a golang implementation where I'll put the condition accordingly.

To do Golang implementation, we can only add a module overriding existing one where Existing modules can be android, apex, cc etc. For reference check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59467685/1944896) Here, apex module is used to write own module on top of it. But in case of `optional_subdirs` it is neither a module nor fall under a module type. because of which I am unable to proceed further. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** `subdirs` and `optional_subdirs` are deprecated since Android Pie (see [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/pie-release:build/soong/root.bp)). From now on all `Android.bp` files will be included by Soong.

#### Option #1

You could update the all modules that refer to `SomeLib` as part of its `shared_libs` or `static_libs` instead of trying to change `optional_subdirs`. This can be done by implementing a custom [Mutator](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/blueprint) in `Soong`.

You can find a lot of examples on how to write custom modules by searching for `bootstrap_go_package` in AOSP.

#### Option #2

If you only want to install the library depending on the device type you can add the library to the `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` list of the `device.mk` files in which you want it to be included (see [here](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/new-device#makefiles)).

Comment: There are multiple places that library is being used. And it will be same work repeated many times unnecessarily i.e. applying that change in every apps. Can we do something in Soong finder itself? I mean asking Soong not to pick this SomeLib for other targets but one?

Comment: I think you can achieve that by writing a `Mutator` that checks every module for using`SomeLib` and then update its `shared_libs` property.

Comment: Okay that is a way, but it still needs some changes in every app's Android.bp i.e. to add that mutator reference to make it work. I want to avoid that too. I'll probably post another question.