# Anyway to control Soong when to pick Android.bp and when not?

Tags: android, android-source

With new build system i.e. `"Soong"`, Android replaced `Android.mk` with `Android.bp`. Also Android Q onward, `Soong` will pick all `Android.bp` files no matter where all are present. Earlier, For 2 level and 3 level modules, it was not picking up Android.bp file unless instructed by `"optional_dirs"`. Now this too has been deprecated. Quoting from android source code's [platform/build/soong/root.bp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/refs/heads/master/root.bp):

```
// Soong finds all Android.bp and Blueprints files in the source tree,
// subdirs= and optional_subdirs= are obsolete and this file no longer
// needs a list of the top level directories that may contain Android.bp
// files.
```

I looked into `Soong` api and found something called ["visibility"](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/master/android/visibility.go), using which we can make a package private or public or hidden; but either way it won't stop `Soong` to pick a package's `Android.bp`. Now there seems no way to say `Soong` not to pick a specific `Android.bp` file for a particular target or for any of the target.

Just to put the question clearly, I should be able to pick and unpick any package's Android.bp based on the target selected at build time. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: I tried reading `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/` and `https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/+/HEAD/docs/best_practices.md#removing-conditionals`, and I think there''ll be a way to pick or skip modules via conditions, but, I personally would like to rename my Android.bp instead to keep soong compatible with future versions.

Comment: @PulathisiBandara How would you handle when you have multiple targets?

Comment: @PulathisiBandara I mean when you rename it instead. I was thinking if there could be golang way of achieving it.

Comment: You're to the point. I would write a shell script to rename unwanted targets' `Android.bp` to something like `Android.bp.bk`. There must be a GoLang way of achieving what you've said, thuough I haven't tried. It's probably would seem changing the default soong build system if you proceed to do so.

Comment: @Pulathisi so far I couldn't find a way to do it from golang, I have done something using golang that you might be interested to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59467685/1944896