# How to exclude directories when build/core looks for Android.mk/.bp during Android image building?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I have an Android repository (Pie based) for a device containing a folder in vendor/companyname which contains many projects I cannot modify for various certification reasons. Some of these projects contain an Android.mk or Android.bp which generate modules that have name collisions with core Android, for example:

```
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:260: error: vendor/companyname/someproject/cpufeatures: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.cpufeatures already defined by prebuilts/ndk
```

I do not need these modules for my device, and therefore want to simply omit them (the source code in these modules is used outside the Android Build System). From what I can see, I should be able to add paths to "SCAN_EXCLUDE_DIRS" in my device/companyname/devicename/BoardConfig.mk to omit all Android.mk/.bp found in vendor/companyname, but it seems to have no effect (the makefile is still included). Is there another way to omit directories from being scanned for Android.mk or Anroid.mk files?

Comment: This question is not related to ```android-ndk``` and ```ndk-build``` tags, it is related to ```aosp```.

Comment: @NikolayKhilyuk Thanks, edited the tags.

Answer (score 1):

As for scripts written in `Soong` (`Android.bp`), there is no way to exclude them from the build at all. This topic was also discussed earlier here: [Anyway to control Soong when to pick Android.bp and when not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980476/anyway-to-control-soong-when-to-pick-android-bp-and-when-not)